# No location provider available, permission denied in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app which requires the user to allow the location. The device I'm testing the app shows no problem to that. But whenever I use another device it shows the following error:

[image]

Here's the code i have:

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      let lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      let long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
      
      let initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }

      this.setState({ initialPosition: initialRegion })
      this.setState({ markerPosition: initialRegion })
    },
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 3600000 }
    )
  }
```

I have tried  `{ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 2000 }`, but it shows the same error.

Comment: your android's version?

Answer (score 9):

From the code you’ve given you haven’t shown that you are requesting authorisation to access the permissions.

You should be calling `navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization();` before you start requesting locations.

You should also make sure you have set the required permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `Info.plist`

You can check the documentation here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation

> Android API >= 23 Requires an additional step to check for, and
>   request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission using the
>   [PermissionsAndroid API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html). Failure to do so may result in a hard crash.

You could do something like this.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

async function requestLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'Location Permission',
        'message': 'This App needs access to your location ' +
                   'so we can know where you are.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use locations ")
    } else {
      console.log("Location permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: did this but still showing the same error @Andrew    https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-86qaji?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Does the app ask you for permission to use the location?

Comment: No it doesn't want my permission to use the location.

Comment: Looking at the code your `componentDidMount` should be like this `async componentDidMount() { await this.requestLocationPermission() }`. You are missing the `async` and `await` keywords. To use location, you have to request permission, if you don't ask for permission then you will never get the location. If you are not seeing the permission dialog. Firstly, do a clean install of the app, delete the previous version and then reinstall on the device. This will remove any previously saved settings.  Then launch the app and make sure that the permission dialog gets displayed.

Comment: Okay. I just removed maximumAge and enabled high accuracy from device location setting and now it doesn't show the error anymore. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

please turn on the location on your device and try it out after that.

Comment: This is one of the reasons, with a new device even if you allow it in pop up and your location is not on you will get this error

Comment: GENIUS!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Setting High Accuracy like this worked for me:

```js
const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
  accuracy:Location.Accuracy.High
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran through this error. Took me a bit to find out that device Location method needs to be kept as High Accuracy in device settings.

Thankyou